# Antonym for force (verb)

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the antonym for the verb force? (i.e. antonym of 'urge or force (a person) to an action')

Comment: Without using the words *force, coerce, urge, antonym* or *opposite*, write a dictionary definition of the word you're looking for. There are many words whose antonym could be *force*. Which one would you like?

Comment: What would the antonym mean? - that they are forced *not* to do it; that they are *not* forced to do it but *are allowed to*; that they do it *willingly* and force is *not needed*;  ... ?

Comment: I assume you mean something like _dissuade_, _hinder_ or _prevent_, but these are not antonyms in the usual sense as larger structures (eg 'She prevented him from leaving') are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a *direct* one. The best you'll probably get is 'allow' or a synonym thereof, such as 'permit', or 'let'.

Alternately, you could make a reasonable case that, for some uses, 'request' or a synonym thereof is a more appropriate choice.